# Google Maps: dynamically change color of complex svg marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I have SVG image that i want to use as a marker for Google Maps, and i need to set different colors for this image, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLkgtc2x/

When I'm using one single path for icon, it's OK, but when instead of

```
var goodIcon = {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: 1
}
```

I'm trying to use actual SVG

```
var icon = {
    url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/7gn.svg',
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: 1
}
```

marker stays black. And looks like I cannot merge all paths into one because i need that white triangle.  Is there any way to have complex and runtime-colored markers?

Comment: set the colours in the svg itself. Use different images if you want different colours.

Comment: Colors should be user-defined, and having svg files for each possible color would be quite troublesome.

Comment: Can you use two markers?  One with a controllable color, the other with the white triangle on top of it?

Comment: In my case marker count can exceed several thousand, so doubling this count doesn't look like good idea too. I'll probably try to generate colored SVGs at the server side on the fly, but maybe someone knows better solution.